# MySQLi: fetch_object

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mysqli

The method below in my class generates a multi-dimensional array, but I only need an one-dimensional array,

```
# return the current row of a result set as an object
    public function fetch_object($query) 
    {
        $result = $this->connection->query($query);
        if($result)
        {
            $function_result = array();
            $i = 0;
            while($row = $result->fetch_object())
            {
                # you should store each row in an array and then return the array
                $function_result[$i] = $row;
                $i++;
            }
            return $function_result;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->get_error();
        }
    }
```

for instance, it creates,

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cnt_id] => 1
            [cnt_email1] => xx@yahoo.co.uk
            [cnt_email2] => 
            [cnt_fullname] => Lau x
            [cnt_firstname] => x
            [cnt_lastname] => Lau
            [cnt_created] => 2011-02-04 00:00:00
            [cnt_updated] => 2011-02-04 13:53:49
        )

)
```

but I actually need this only,

```
Array
(
    [cnt_id] => 1
    [cnt_email1] => xx@yahoo.co.uk
    [cnt_email2] => 
    [cnt_fullname] => Lau x
    [cnt_firstname] => x
    [cnt_lastname] => Lau
    [cnt_created] => 2011-02-04 00:00:00
    [cnt_updated] => 2011-02-04 13:53:49
)
```

How can I fix the code to generate one-dimensional array only?

Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that this would mean that your SQL query may _never_ return more than one single row? And if it did, everything but the last row would be discarded. If that is desired, just leave the index and use `$function_result = $row;` and `$result->fetch_assoc` instead of `$result->fetch_object`? Furthermore, this _is_ a one-dimensional array, containing objects. The `var_dump` just looks _similar_ to a two-dimensional array, but it isn't the same.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. made the code complicated. i have answered my own question! lol

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my mistake, I should have written it like this,

```
# return the current row of a result set as an object
    public function fetch_object($query) 
    {
        $result = parent::query($query);
        if($result)
        {
            return $result->fetch_object();
        }
        else
        {
            # call the get_error function
            return self::get_error();
            # or:
            # return $this->get_error();
        }

    }
```